# php opencart method inside class not define but can be called?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, opencart

I'm reading opencart php source code, and I can't figure this out. 
Please take a look at function rewrite() at "$url = $rewrite->rewrite($url);"

```
<?php
class Url {
    private $url;
    private $rewrite = array();

    public function link($route, $args = '', $connection = 'NONSSL') {
    ....

        foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {
            $url = $rewrite->rewrite($url);
        }
        return $url;
    }

public function addRewrite($rewrite) {
    $this->rewrite[] = $rewrite;
}
}
?>
```

Why above code doesn't generate error ? 
The rewrite function is not defined in class Url, and class Url doesn't extend anybody ?? 
But then I track deeper, it seems that function rewrite is at seo_url class.

```
class ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
    // Add rewrite to url class
    if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
        $this->url->addRewrite($this);
    }
    ...
    public function rewrite($link) {
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $url_data = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));
             ....
```

Why ? I don't see any connection between 'Url' and this 'ControllerCommonSeoUrl' yet. Am I missing some concept here ? What I should do to understand these codes ? Need little guidance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {
```

Iterates over whatever values in:

```
private $rewrite = array();
```

And maybe that `Url->rewrite` array contains an instance of `ControllerCommonSeoUrl`, that would explain why `$rewrite->rewrite()` calls `ControllerCommonSeoUrl->rewrite()`.

Also, you'd do yourself a favor by trying to learn to use a debugger :)

Comment: I updated the partial code with addRewrite function inside url class. Yeah you are right! Url class has addRewrite( obj url ) , and the 'ControllerCommonSeoUrl' class call this with this line : "$this->url->addRewrite($this);"

Answer (score 0):

check if the controller is loading any model in the script if so , the model method can be simply accessed inside the script which might be the case with your script as $this->rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The `Url` class is a generic class that can have multiple URL rewrite method's called, making it possible for people to change the URL rewriting code. Triggering the SEO URL code to add it to the `Url` class is done in the `index.php` file by the following

```
// SEO URL's
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));
```

When that Action is executed, the `ControllerCommonSeoUrl` executed the `index()` method, and as with the code you provided, it checks if SEO URL's are active in the settings. If they are, then the current class is added to the array of rewrite's in the `Url` class. Then whenever someone calls `$this->url->link()` each of the rewrite classes have their `rewrite()` method called and the subsequent URL is passed back